# Linux - migrating accounts and emails from server with cPanel to one without one

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, centos

I have a few accounts of my own on shared hosting that has cPanel. Each account has websites + databases which I can/know how to migrate, and each account has several emails with filters (forwards). I'll set up a linux node without cPanel, and maybe I'll put webmin on it. Can I somehow migrate those email accounts without opening each one from scratch on new server and assigning passwords and redirects anew? I'd appreciate any pointers. I've tried googling, to no avail so far.

Comment: Can we ask why you decied to give up on cPanel?

Comment: @Marco - sure. It's basically several of my own sites which I would like to migrate from shared hosting to linode node. I love cPanel and WHM (both of which I have on shared hosting now), but I don't use any of it pretty much. Only mail creation and filtering and account creation here and there in whm, and that alone doesn't justify an expense I'd have with having to pay for it on my own node. Tough times. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install virtualmin (webmin web hosting panel addon):

Virtualmin have a cpanel accounts import tool.

http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/id,virtualmin_for_cpanel_users/#using_the_migration_form

Best regards

roberto

Comment: virtualmin link:

http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html

roberto

Comment: thanks, I just can't find information if that is available in GPL version, or professional/commercial version is needed?

Comment: Take a look this link:

http://www.virtualmin.com/download.html

There are a GPL and commercial version.

You should install virtualmin in a fresh minimal install Centos server, then import the cpanel accounts.